# Error Couldn't load provisioning profile from data

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I don't know what happened, Yesterday all the provisioning and certificates were working fine but today I don't know I unable to make the build , am always getting error `Couldn't load provisioning from data`.I only make a change into system I just update my iTunes 11 to 12 but I don't know how it can affect my xCode configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to delete your account and add again.

Comment: @HemantSinghRathore I already did but nothing helps me.

Comment: Same thing also happened to me yesterday.  Clicked the Install button in a dialog that said a software update was required to connect to an iOS 12 device and now XCode can't load provisioning from data.

Comment: @mbonness same exact thing happened to me. Installing Xcode 10 magically fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error using XCode 9.2 and iTunes 12.8 running on macOS Sierra, and (sort of) fixed it as follows:

1. Uninstall iTunes 12.8 as shown [here](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/uninstall-itunes/).
2. Download/install iTunes 12.6 from Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes).
3. Launch XCode and accept any prompts to install updates.
4. Go to build target, uncheck "Automatically manage signing", and select provisioning profile manually.
5. Build / run the app.

After doing all that the provisioning error went away, however I was getting launch denied errors so I had to go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run and uncheck "Debug executable" in order to get the app to launch.

The better long term fix is probably to upgrade to XCode 10...

Answer (score 0):

Not the same case, but I got the same error for manual and automatic provisioning profile loading.
My case: migration from one mac to another, so I added new certificate to the profile. 
It didn't work unless I **remove old certificate** from the profile.